# Copying Matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I want to copy a matrix so that changing a value in the copy doesn't change the value in the original. I understand why the following is incorrect:

```
matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
matrix2 = matrix1
matrix2[0][0] = 9
matrix2  # [[9, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
matrix1  # [[9, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
matrix2 is matrix1  # True
```

My original approach was this:

```
matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
matrix2 = matrix1[:][:]
matrix2[0][0] = 9
matrix2  # [[9, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
matrix1  # [[9, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
matrix2 is matrix1  # False
```

In the second code excerpt, `matrix1` and `matrix2` do not reference the same object. **Why then, do changes in `matrix2` still affect `matrix1`?** I was of the understanding that if they are separate objects, then changing one will not change the other, which is the reason why the slicing notation works for a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: `matrix1[:][:]` just makes a copy of a copy. It doesn't copy the sublists.

Comment: Try `[matrix1[k] is matrix2[k] for k in range(len(matrix1))]`.

Comment: To explain it a bit further, it makes a **shallow** copy of a shallow copy (means, the items in each row are still the same items since it's two-dimensional). See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: I am aware that questions asking about how to copy matrices in Python are already answered on SO. I am asking why the double-slicing notation does not work as I expected, despite `matrix1` and `matrix2` referencing different objects.

Comment: @user2357112 hmm, would you be able to expand on that a bit more? I imagine this is the answer to my question!

Comment: To rephrase what @user2357112 said (it just took me a while to understand): `matrix1[:][:]` is essentially the same as `matrix1[:]` or `matrix1[:][:][:][:]` (just all of these would have different `id`s). You keep copying the outermost list, since python doesn't know that this is a matrix. So you keep referencing (rather than copying) what's inside each list, i.e. each row. If you want to do it safely, you can use (`deepcopy` or) `matrix2=[k[:] for k in matrix1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `[:]` produces a copy of the outermost list. The second `[:]` produces another copy of the outermost list.

What you want to do is called a "deep copy". Take a look at the `copy` module: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy